# Create Hoverable popover using angular-ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following code for creating a popover in my template file:

```
<span class="icon-globe visibility" 
      id="visibilityFor{{post.metaData.assetId}}" 
      popover="{{post.visibilityListStr}}" 
      popover-placement="right" 
      popover-trigger="mouseenter" 
      popover-popup-delay="50" 
      visibility>
</span>
```

I have a few clickable links on the popover. But the problem is I'm not able to hover on the popover created. I referred to the link http://jsfiddle.net/xZxkq/
and tried to create a directive viz. 'visibility' for this purpose.

Here is the code:

```
myAppModule.directive("visibility", function ($timeout,$rootScope) {
  return {

    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.attachEvents = function (element) {
            $('.popover').on('mouseenter', function () {
                $rootScope.insidePopover = true;
            });
            $('.popover').on('mouseleave', function () {
                $rootScope.insidePopover = false;
                $(element).popover('hide');
            });
        }
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $rootScope.insidePopover = false;

        element.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (!$rootScope.insidePopover) {
                    element.popover('show');
                    attachEvents(element);
                }
            }, 200);
        });

        element.bind('mouseout', function (e) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (!$rootScope.insidePopover) {
                    element.popover('show');
                    attachEvents(element);
                }
            }, 200);
        });

    }
  }
});
```

But I get an exception for 'element.popover' since it is undefined. Please point as to what I'm doing wrong and how can I show/hide the angular ui popover from the directive. I am using angular ui bootstrap JS file.

Comment: See [my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674706/4826740)

Answer (score 13):

I have solved it in a very cleaned way and thought to share it:

**.popover** is being created not as a child of the **uib-popover**
so the idea is to wrap **uib-popover** with a parent and to control show&hide on hovering the parent.

**.popover** and **uib-popover** are children of this parent
so just left to set **popover-trigger=none** and you have what you are wishing for.

I created a [plunk example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6vzrrH1KUyQeLHDz1hWp?p=preview):

```
<span ng-init="popoverOpened=false" ng-mouseover="popoverOpened=true" ng-mouseleave="popoverOpened=false">
    <button class="btn btn-default" uib-popover-html="htmlPopover" 
            popover-trigger="none" popover-placement="bottom-left" popover-is-open="popoverOpened" >
       <span>hover me</span>
    </button>
</span>
```

enjoy.

Comment: I tried almost all of the solutions in this page, this was the best one.

Comment: While this isn't the most elegant solution, it ended up being the easiest for me to implement. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: word of caution: it doesn't work with popover-append-to-body="true"

Comment: it is working with popover-append-to-body="true" just add popover-class. i have it working in my app.

Comment: @oded sorry to reopen this after such a long time but can you elaborate a bit more on how adding `popover-class` would make this work with append to body? Cheers

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is relevant to the OP anymore, but I've had the same problem and fortunately I managed to solve it.

**Undefined error**

First thing first, the undefined error you are getting might be (at least in my case) because you are using the development version of `ui-bootstrap`. In my case I got this error when trying to bind `element.popover`. After adding the minified version of the library the error went away.

**Keep the popover open when hovering over it**

To do this I have created a custom directive that makes use of the `popover` from the `ui-bootstrap` library.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('hoverPopover', function ($compile, $templateCache, $timeout, $rootScope) {
var getTemplate = function (contentType) {
    return $templateCache.get('popoverTemplate.html');
};
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var content = getTemplate();
        $rootScope.insidePopover = false;
        $(element).popover({
            content: content,
            placement: 'top',
            html: true
        });
        $(element).bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (!$rootScope.insidePopover) {
                    $(element).popover('show');
                    scope.attachEvents(element);
                }
            }, 200);
        });
        $(element).bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
            $timeout(function () {
                if (!$rootScope.insidePopover)
                    $(element).popover('hide');
            }, 400);
        });
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $scope.attachEvents = function (element) {
            $('.popover').on('mouseenter', function () {
                $rootScope.insidePopover = true;
            });
            $('.popover').on('mouseleave', function () {
                $rootScope.insidePopover = false;
                $(element).popover('hide');
            });
        }
    }
};
});
```

This directive also accepts a custom template for the popover, so you are not limited to just title and some text in it. You can create your own html template and feed it to the control.

**Usage**

```
<a href="#" hover-popover>Click here</a>
```

Hopes this helps someone else in the future :)

**Edit**

As requested, here is a [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/6awhrcec/). It lacks the styling, but it should demonstrate the way it works.

Comment: will you please host it on fiddle?

Comment: @Laxmikant Dange I've added a fiddle link in the answer

Comment: Maybe you should note that this solution requires JQuery

Comment: @tatsuhirosatou Well taking into account that this is Angular 1.x we're talking about I guess it shouldn't be a problem since Angular requires jQuery to run.

Comment: @CosminIonascu Angular does not require jQuery to run and many people go to great lengths to avoid having jQuery as a dependency on their code. https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

Comment: i see this: $(...).popover is not a function error :(

Answer (score 6):

There I spend 1 day and finally get solution.

```
<button uib-popover="{{dynamicPopover.content}}" 
    popover-trigger="outsideClick" popover-is-open="popoverIsOpen"
    ng-mouseenter="popoverIsOpen = !popoverIsOpen" 
    popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dynamic Popover</button>
```

Please check
[Plunkeer Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/CXazDeJw3ymWek58UIRE?p=preview)
Check only Dynamic Popover button code

Thanks,

Comment: This is working with **popover-append-to-body="true"**, not like other answers. But I needed change this **popover-trigger="outsideClick"** for this **popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"** (simple quotation marks inside double quotation marks)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I think Cosmin has the hoverable popover right, but it does seem to be using the Twitter Bootstrap popover method. The idea is to have this hoverable popover implemented only with AngularJS and one of the Bootstrap wrappers for AngularJS, which are [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/).

So I have put together an implementation which uses only AngularStrap:

```
myApp.directive('hoverablePopover', function ($rootScope, $timeout, $popover) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (!scope.insidePopover) {

                        scope.popover.show();
                        scope.attachEventsToPopoverContent();
                    }
                }, 200);
            });

            element.bind('mouseout', function (e) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (!scope.insidePopover) {

                        scope.popover.hide();
                    }
                }, 400);
            });

        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            //The $attrs will server as the options to the $popover.
            //We also need to pass the scope so that scope expressions are supported in the  popover attributes
            //like title and content.
            $attrs.scope = $scope;
            var popover = $popover($element, $attrs);
            $scope.popover = popover;
            $scope.insidePopover = false;

            $scope.attachEventsToPopoverContent = function () {

                $($scope.popover.$element).on('mouseenter', function () {

                    $scope.insidePopover = true;

                });
                $($scope.popover.$element).on('mouseleave', function () {

                    $scope.insidePopover = false;
                    $scope.popover.hide();

                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

When you have a popover element, you need to take into account that you have the element that triggers the popover and you also have the element with the actual popover content.

The idea is to keep the popover open when you mouse over the element with the actual popover content. In the case of my directive, the link function takes care of the element that triggers the popover and attaches the mouseenter/mouseout event handlers.

The controller takes care of setting the scope and the popover itself via the AngularStrap $popover service. The controller adds the popover object returned by the AngularStrap service on the scope so that it is available in the link function. It also adds a method `attachEventsToPopoverContent`, which attaches the mouseenter/mouseout events to the element with the popover content.

The usage of this directive is like this:

```
  <a title="Popover Title" data-placement="left" data-trigger="manual" data-content="{{someScopeObject}}" content-template="idOfTemplateInTemplateCache" hoverablePopover="">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the trigger in single quotes, because, reasons:

```
<button uib-popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Mouseenter</button>
```

Comment: this is true answer. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

demo:

https://jsbin.com/fuwarekeza/1/edit?html,output

directive:

```
myAppModule.directive('popoverHoverable', ['$timeout', '$document', function ($timeout, $document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            popoverHoverable: '=',
            popoverIsOpen: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.insidePopover = false;

            scope.$watch('insidePopover', function (insidePopover) {
                togglePopover(insidePopover);
            })

            scope.$watch('popoverIsOpen', function (popoverIsOpen) {
                scope.insidePopover = popoverIsOpen;
            })

            function togglePopover (isInsidePopover) {
                $timeout.cancel(togglePopover.$timer);
                togglePopover.$timer = $timeout(function () {
                    if (isInsidePopover) {
                        showPopover();
                    } else {
                        hidePopover();
                    }
                }, 100)
            }

            function showPopover () {
                if (scope.popoverIsOpen) {
                    return;
                }

                $(element[0]).click();
            }

            function hidePopover () {
                scope.popoverIsOpen = false;
            }

            $(document).bind('mouseover', function (e) {
                var target = e.target;
                if (inside(target)) {
                    scope.insidePopover = true;
                    scope.$digest();
                }
            })

            $(document).bind('mouseout', function (e) {
                var target = e.target;
                if (inside(target)) {
                    scope.insidePopover = false;
                    scope.$digest();
                }
            })

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                $(document).unbind('mouseenter');
                $(document).unbind('mouseout');
            })

            function inside (target) {
                return insideTrigger(target) || insidePopover(target);
            }

            function insideTrigger (target) {
                return element[0].contains(target);
            }

            function insidePopover (target) {
                var isIn = false;
                var popovers = $('.popover-inner');
                for (var i = 0, len = popovers.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (popovers[i].contains(target)) {
                        isIn = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return isIn;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

html:

```
<span class="icon-globe visibility" 
      id="visibilityFor{{post.metaData.assetId}}" 
      popover="{{post.visibilityListStr}}" 
      popover-is-open="{{post.$open}}"
      popover-trigger="click" 
      popover-hoverable="true"
      visibility>
</span>
```

Comment: how this is going to work with multiple popovers? can't create separate variable for each of them to maintain open/close state

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
 <span class="icon-globe" id="visibilityFor" popover="hello how are you" 
       popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter" 
       popover-popup-delay="50" viz>
</span>
```

**directive**

```
myAppModule.directive('viz', function ($rootScope,$timeout){
    return{

        restrict:"A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $rootScope.insidePopover = false;

            element.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (!$rootScope.insidePopover) {
                        element.popover('show');
                     //  attachEvents(element);
                    }
                }, 200);
            });

            element.bind('mouseout', function (e) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (!$rootScope.insidePopover) {
                        element.popover('show');
                     //   attachEvents(element);
                    }
                }, 200);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

**Note :** - Don't forget to include **angular-strap** after **jQuery.js & angular.js**

Comment: Still gives the same error. "Object doesn't support property or method 'popover'"

Comment: It is tested by me and run fine with me So check your other javascript code and file. or Make fiddle of your code and let me check it.

Comment: You are on about a COMPLETELY different library. This question is for Angular-UI Bootstrap, you answered it for Angular-Strap.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was added in Angular UI Bootstrap 0.14.0 and is documented [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover).  Disable the triggers and use the `popover-is-open` property to manually dictate the opened/closed state.

Answer (score 0):

What I did that gets my by in 0.13.X is to set the element to be hoverable to a `<button>` and then set the popover-trigger="focus". Then style the button how you wish, and focus the button by clicking it. You can hover in the popover and click a link, all I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way to have a mouse-event using uib-popover**
Look at the below working example !
You need not have a **uib-tabset**, I faced an issue with uib-tabset and so added that example.

```
<uib-tabset>
      <uib-tab>
        <uib-tab-heading>
          Tab 1
        </uib-tab-heading>
        <div>

          <span ng-mouseover="popoverIsOpen = true" 
                ng-mouseleave="popoverIsOpen = false">
            <button uib-popover-template="'includeFile.html'"
                    popover-trigger="outsideClick" 
                    popover-is-open="popoverIsOpen"
                    popover-placement="right"
                    type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              Dynamic Popover
            </button>
        </span>

        </div>
        <p> tab 1</p>
      </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab>
        <uib-tab-heading>
          Tab 2
        </uib-tab-heading>

        <p> tab 2</p>
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
```

Template: **includeFile.html**

```
<div>
  <span>This is for tesitng</span>
  <strong> <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></strong>

</div>
```

Comment: Working example of the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/9oMYadXPNJcRPrig71iF?p=preview

Comment: this doesn't work with popover-append-to-body="true"

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this as well. I have a checkbox in a table cell that can have 3 possible states: Enabled, Disabled, or Special case. The UI spec I have asked for a popover over the box that shows either of those statuses, or for the special case a sentence with a link.

I tried several of these solutions and one of them worked for me, and they all added extra code. After some playing around, I determined I could just add the "popover-popup-close-delay" attribute with a dynamic value. So this works for me:

```
<td uib-popover-html="getPopoverTxt()" popover-popup-close-delay="{{ele.isspecial ? 2000 : 300}}" popover-popup-delay="300" popover-append-to-body="true" popover-placement="top" popover-trigger="mouseenter">
    <input id="issynced{{ele.id}}" name="isChecked" type="checkbox" data-ng-checked="ele.ischecked" data-ng-model="ele.ischecked">
    <label for="issynced{{ele.id}}"></label>
</td>
```

Some context: My table is looping over an array of data objects, so ele is a single object. The getPopoverTxt() is just a simple method in my controller that returns one of the 3 labels I want to show ("Enabled", "Disabled", or "Special Text with HTML"). Its not necessary here, but the takeaway is to get the HTML to work, you have to wrap the string value in $sce.trustAsHtml(), like:

```
var specialText = $sce.trustAsHtml('Text with a link to <a href="/help" target="_blank">contact support</a>');
```

The rest is all the usual popover and form input settings we normally use. The "popover-popup-close-delay" is the key.