# How can I use popover via javascript in angularjs module with ui.bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I use popover via javascript in angularjs module with ui.bootstrap?

I am looking a solution like $modal service.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Documentation: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

Comment: Alessandro, please could you specify ? I expected a service look-like $popover... but I didn't find it. Re-edit: more information on: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/590

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how you want to use popover like a service. $modal service is a shortcut to open a modal (only one instance in your app). Popover let you specify a popover as many elements as you want.

Comment: Do you want to trigger the popover without click/mouseenter?

Comment: I would like $watch the mouseenter event on a picture. When this event is fired, I would like to do some code like this: $popover({options}). With options could be some thing like this:    {content: pictureTag, html:true }

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a **declarative** framework. It's a bad style to use **imperative** behavior like calling a function when a event happen.

You can get what you want with a new directive, for your special case "image that popover a text when mouseenter". Refer to this [Create Hoverable popover using angular-ui-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267967/create-hoverable-popover-using-angular-ui-bootstrap)

Comment: Dear Alessandro, thks so much for your helping. In fact at this time, ui.bootstrap doesn't implement the popover service as angular-strap did it. I suppose that the AngularUI team should implement it asap according this issue: github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/590. Your solution is around angular-strap & I wanted before use a solution with ui.bootstrap.