# Angular create a mouseenter popover that you can click

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a popover which you can click.  AngularUI has a nice way of indicating a delay for how long you need to hover for a popover to appear, but I need a similar directive that allows me to click inside the popover.  I can't do this because it automatically disappears on mouseleave.  I could use something like popover-close-delay, but I also want to ensure that there is only one popover open at a time.  Ideally, hovering on a popover would work the same as hovering on its parent element.

I also found this, but I can't get it to work and I suspect it may be related to AngularStrap and not the bootstrap ui. [Create Hoverable popover using angular-ui-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267967/create-hoverable-popover-using-angular-ui-bootstrap)

Here is my code

```
  <div style="width:50px" popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" 
  popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-popup-delay=600>Item 1</div>
  <div style="width:50px" popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" 
  popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-popup-delay=600>Item 2</div>
  <div style="width:50px" popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" 
  popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-popup-delay=600>Item 3</div>
  <div style="width:50px" popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" 
  popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-popup-delay=600>Item 4</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/moHGYOdmIOE4IFDOICKs?p=preview

Comment: If I may paraphrase- you want to a. hover over an element b. have popover appear c. click on popover. The only way to do this is to create a directive that  uses popover markup within the div that is recording the mouseover event. Otherwise the popover will disappear on mouseout of your hoverable element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to create your own.  You could probably do what you want this way (editing [tooltip.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js)):

1. add a delay between `mouseleave` and closing the popover to give you time to move your mouse to the popover
2. bind events to the popover element itself as well, so you track it's mouseenter/mouseleave
3. keep a counter of elements inside, incremented on mouseenter and decremented on mouseleave.  Only finally close the tooltip if the counter is 0 after the leave delay

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable.  How can I accomplish item #2?

Comment: Look for bind() and unbind() calls and call them on the `tooltip` element when it is created and removed.