# Ng-click inside Popover for Angular UI-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the fairly excellent [UI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), and combined with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722424/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-popover-with-html-content), I'm successfully including HTML inside our popovers.

The problem we're having is that we want to compile the HTML inside these Popovers, because it includes a button with an `ng-click` directive, which hopefully triggers a bootstrap-modal dialog.

Is there anything we can do? Or any alternatives to get Bootstrap Popovers with buttons that can trigger  modals?

Comment: So your issue is you want a popover to be editable using an HTML template? Rather than just using popover="" ?

Comment: Well it's not really important that it's editable. Functionally, what I'm interested in is: being able to trigger a modal from a button in a popover.