# newline in popover text from scope

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, popover

I'm using `angular-ui` popover.
The popover text is `{{popoverText}}` so the HTML won't be filled with tons of text (and it is more correct to put it in the controller.

I defined `$scope.popoverText` in the contoller.

How can I make a newline in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an AngularJS UI bootstrap popover with HTML content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722424/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-popover-with-html-content)