# How to import html table with progressbar in ui bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have this table, and i want to insert it into ui-bootstrap popover:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="p in probs"><label ng-bind="p.name"></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="p in probs">
                <progressbar animate="false" value="p.Probability" type="success"><b ng-bind="p.Probability+'%'"></b></progressbar>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and here is what i have in my controller:

$scope.probs = [
        {
            name: 'first',
            Probability: '30'
        },
        {
            name: 'second',
            Probability: '40'
        },
        {
            name: 'third',
            Probability: '30'
        },
        ];

simple list with progress bar, i want on mouseenter on some div to display this table inside the popover...Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an AngularJS UI bootstrap popover with HTML content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722424/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-popover-with-html-content)

Comment: i could not find the answer there, since the example is totally different, anyone have idea?