# tooltip in angularjs with "uib-tooltip-html"

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I try to implement a tooltip with angularjs template inside. For this, I use "uib-tooltip-html" and I add an attribute on the element to compile the template. But it doesn't work.
Here is the code
Here is the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/y1TvogsFFBoBVra3gO3F?p=preview

```
   <html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>uib-tooltip-html test</title>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("test", ['ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap']).config(function($sceProvider) {
            $sceProvider.enabled(false);
        });

        app.controller("testController", function($scope, $http, $interval, $sce) {
          $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml('<table><tr ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]"><td>{{ x }}</td></tr></table>');
        });
        app.directive('compileTemplate', function($compile, $parse){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var parsed = $parse(attr.uibTooltipHtml);
            console.log(attr.uibTooltipHtml);

            function getStringValue() { return (parsed(scope) || '').toString(); }
            console.log(getStringValue())
            //Recompile if the template changes
            scope.$watch(getStringValue, function() {
              console.log('ca passe');
                $compile(element, null, -9999)(scope);  //The -9999 makes it skip directives so that we do not recompile ourselves
            });
        }         
    }
});
    </script>

    </head>
<body>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">

    <p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip="Some text" >
        A Thing With a Tooltip
    </p>

    <p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip-html="text" compile-template>
        A Thing With an HTML Tooltip
    </p>

</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28189625/1061668

Answer (score 16):

You can use `uib-tooltip-template` like this:

```
<p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip-template="'myTooltipTemplate.html'">
    A Thing With an HTML Tooltip
</p>
```

And then in put your html in myTooltipTemplate.html:

```
<table><tr ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]"><td>{{ x }}</td></tr></table>
```

The template goes in a separate file.

documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/tiCHpd0LipixXbO4Xfa5?p=preview

Comment: How would this work with dynamic content?  I love that it is simple, but I am not seeing how I could do something like this:  `<div class="dol-type" uib-tooltip="{{ GetWorkingDays('YTD TY') }}">Actual TY</div>` where it will return "Month: 24<br />YTD: 45"?

Comment: @Grandizer, the template works just as an "include" of the html to be rendered, so It will work within the context of your div. For example: 
    <div class="dol-type" uib-tooltip-template="'workingdays.html'">ACTUAL TY</div>
and you can still call the function in workingdays.html:
    <div>{{ GetWorkingDays('YTD TY') }}</div>

Comment: I guess that is my issue, the `"YTD TY"` changes.  So what variable is the "expression" or $event or something that I can pass through?

Comment: You can still use your variable in the template. The template works within the context where it is used. Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/SpcFxR4Z28ztkIsO3ozW?p=preview

Comment: I see what you did there.  Thank you.