# $Compile An Html String with Ng-Repeat Into...Compiled Html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, compilation

I have a tooltip that takes raw javascript, for example I have this $scope var:

```
  $scope.dynamicPopoverContent = "Hello, <b>World!</b>";
```

that I can display by passing it to the popover directive like so:

```
popover="{{dynamicPopoverContent}}"
```

I cannot readily use templates because I am using an old version of angular-bootstrap. I want to use ng-repeat inside  `$scope.dynamicPopoverContent` - can I use `$compile`here somehow to compile html with angular directives into compiled html, or is that just for the link function on directives?

[PLNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ACP1LOqzRuN2zBze5cA?p=preview)

Edit: ...and if I could use directives inside that html....

Comment: Older angular bootstrap didn't support html for content

Comment: Someone hacked it to do so. See first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722424/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-popover-with-html-content or see the plunk in the question. That said, I am probably just going to build  the html by hand in javascript...fun.