# Add html in angular popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-popover

How will I pass html content to angular popover. I have written code like below

```
<a popover="{{tooltipValue}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" href="#"><img class="img" /></a>
```

In above code on hover of image pop up will come, but if text contains some tag like 
 then it will show as is . How to I display html tags. I know data-html-bind will do the job, but I don't know how to use it here.

Comment: Refer this link.. [Create an AngularJS UI popover with HTML content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722424/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-popover-with-html-content)

Comment: The docs show some examples how to accomplish this. also use `uib-popover-template` instead of `popover`