# Angular 1.5 Binding ng-repeat created controls?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope

**Angular 1.5**

In an `ng-repeat` I create a button that will display a `Bootstrap popup` with anchor links.

How do I bind the `onAction` call so that it calls my `$scope.onAction()` function ? (onAction() is not bound to $scope.onAction().)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in model.Holdings  track by $index" bs-popover>

  <button class="popoverBtn" 
        data-content="<a ng-click='onAction(1)'>Buy</a>...and more"
          click me to show popup
  </button>

</div>
```

Here's my directive that turns the Bootstrap popover on:

```
app.directive('bsPopover', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find(".popoverBtn").popover({ placement: 'auto', html: 'true' });

    ????COMPILE GOES HERE???////
    };
});
```

Comment: The <button> tag is incomplete, and I'm not sure if data-content would be properly understood with angle brackets for all browsers. Something there smells off. Usually directives have a template that constructs the HTML within it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the onAction method to take an item identifier.

Perhaps something like `<a ng-click='onAction(item.id)'>Buy</a>` ??

From what I recall, you are in the scope of the controller that stores the data. If you have nested ng-repeats, look into $parent.

Comment: Sorry, no, the problem is that onAction() is never called. It's not bound to the $scope

Comment: Mind posting a little more - perhaps include the tag where you use ngController? (E.G. if you are doing a "Controller As" then you need to identify that specific controller on the action like "model.onAction(1)")

Comment: Oh - Wait a minute ... Are you trying to create page with a button such that when you click the button, it pops up a bootstrap div, such that within that div it contains an anchor the user could click on to trigger the onAction angular method? There's something similar to this request here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722424/how-do-i-create-an-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-popover-with-html-content

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pass the index value of an item into your function on a click event, you need only pass it `$index` instead of an explicit value. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in model.Holdings track by $index">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" 
        data-content="<a ng-click='onAction($index)'>Buy</a>...and more">
    click me to show popup
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem isn't passing$index  data, it's that the onAction() doesn't get called. Once open, I need to $compile the dynamically generated Bootstrap popup,

Answer (score 0):

UI-Bootstrap project seems to have simple to use controls for Angular + Bootstrap.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

This worked